# Can I access resource with File object?

Tags: java, file, fonts, jar, embedded-resource

I was accessing font resource with the following code

```
      try {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("");
            log.debug("url = '{}'", url.toString());

            URI uri = url.toURI();
            log.debug("uri = '{}'", uri.toString());

            File dir = new File(uri);

            files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ttf");
                }
            });

            indice = new Integer[files.length];
            delegate = new Descr[files.length];
            fileNames = new String[files.length];
            fontNames = new String[files.length];

            for(int i=0; i<files.length; ++i) {
                delegate[i] = new Descr(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, files[i]).deriveFont(FontSize));
                fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
                fontNames[i] = delegate[i].getFont().getFontName();
            }



        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

It was working until put into `JAR`. In `JAR` it causes and error

```
 IllegalargumentException: URI is not hierarchicalhierarchical
```

So, how to enumerate resources inside `JAR`? Is it possible to use `File`?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I access resource with File object?

No, they are not files anymore.

> how to enumerate resources inside JAR? Is it possible to use File?

Whenever someone ask that question I wonder why on Earth they'd need to do so.  When building the Jar, create a list of the resources and put in in a 'known location' in the Jar.  At run-time, get the list, parse it, and go from there.

Comment: Of course I will hardcode a list if it is impossible to generate it. In my case these are fonts and it would be great to add new ones easily.

Comment: Was there a point to making that comment?  If so, it is lost on me.